# how can i get a prompt on url change

Tags: java, gwt

i am new in gwt . I want when a user press back button he get a alert that page will we refresh .mostly we see during typing on loose focus if user press back button his page get refresh and all value goes wash. how can we achieve this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Window#ClosingEvent](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.ClosingEvent.html)

```
Window.addWindowClosingHandler(new ClosingHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onWindowClosing(ClosingEvent event) {
        event.setMessage("Message");
    }
});
```

Please have a look at [promt user on backspace and browser backbutton in gwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23291882/promt-user-on-backspace-and-browser-backbutton-in-gwt?answertab=votes#tab-top) where I have mentioned other ways also.

For more info have a look at below posts:

- [GWT back button browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797907/gwt-back-button-browser)
- [Best way to detect browser closing/navigation to other page and do logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888483/best-way-to-detect-browser-closing-navigation-to-other-page-and-do-logout)

Snapshot:

[image]

Comment: thanks it work but when I press back space it is calling previous class i need to prompt user on back space..please help

Comment: OK Let me share you some links.

Comment: Please have a look at [How can I prevent the backspace key from navigating back?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495219/how-can-i-prevent-the-backspace-key-from-navigating-back?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Comment: Try to debug it. It should work. There are lots of answers. try other one also.

Comment: OK Let me try to understand what happens if you press backspace in textfield?

Comment: I am using history class . when i press back space its history token goes change . how can i prompt user when history change

Comment: Please read it carefully. use [History.addValueChangeHandler()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/History.html) which listens for changes in the browser's history.

Comment: I used history change listener but i am getting prompt both time . once a new history item create and second value change of history on back space

Comment: and i have to create value change handler for every class

Answer (score 0):

this will work but result is same

```
  RootPanel.get().addDomHandler(new KeyUpHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent event) {
        if (event.getNativeKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_BACKSPACE) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}, KeyUpEvent.getType());
```